# Can't pass data result to textview in android

Tags: java, android

I have create a simple covert program, which can get input from user and select the type of number that want to covert. Click button OK and return result in the same activity. It look like below image. But when I click the button to return value, it cannot work or return the result and show the program unfortunately, program has stopped? How can I pass it to textview correctly?y in result(textview) in the same activity. It look like in this image.

[image]

below is my code

```
public class activity_tv9 extends tv9 { 
private int mb;
private int tb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tv9_act);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
EditText editview = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
RadioButton rdb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
RadioButton rdb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
final RadioGroup rdg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int value =rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rd=(RadioButton)findViewById(value);
         if(rdg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){
                Toast.makeText(activity_tv9.this,"Please select radio button",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }  
         else {
             switch (rd.getText().toString()){
                case "MB":
                    double mb = Integer.parseInt(editview.getText().toString());
                    double val1 = mb*1024;
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(val1));
                     break;
                case "TB":
                    double tb = Integer.parseInt(editview.getText().toString());
                    double val2 = tb*1024;
                    tv.setText(String.valueOf(val2));
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(activity_tv9.this,"No input",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
         }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Are you sure `tv9` extends Activity or `AppCompatActivity`? Rest i can tell after you post error log.

Comment: @Jaymin "Unfortunately, Program has stopped", that is message. After I enter the value in editview and choose type of convert and click button Ok.

Comment: @PhearumChheang this is what you get on mobile screen but in android studio you have a complete log.

Comment: @jackjay java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: make `tv` as a `final` variable.

Comment: @Jaymin I found the problem, my problem is I can't pass the value to textview. I do it like this"Toast.makeText(activity_tv9.this,"Thanks "+val1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" to test, it works

Comment: @jackjay I add already but not works. I found the problem, my problem is I can't pass the value to textview. I do it like this"Toast.makeText(activity_tv9.this,"Thanks "+val1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" to test, it works

Comment: First check that id of textview is correct? Second instead of `Integer.parseInt()` use `Double.parseDouble()`. Third if `String.valueOf()` is not working try `Double.toString(val)`.

Comment: @jackjay I found that, I have a set to textview but no get method to get data from val1. but I don't how to get and set to textview.

Comment: `val1` is `double` variable, you can access its value directly, you dont need any get method. Also to get text of TextView use `tv.getText()`.

Comment: @jackjay it works. I have put the wrong ID of textview. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `Integer.parseInt(editview.getText().toString())` to `Double.parseDouble(editview.getText().toString())` as you are expecting a `double` value from `editview`:-

```
double mb = Double.parseDouble(editview.getText().toString());
                double val1 = mb*1024;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(val1));
```

Hope this work;

Comment: I would give you +1, if you provide reason. :-)

Comment: @jackjay use variable double but value converted in Integer

Comment: Add the explanation to your answer. In future always try to give explained answers, Thanks.

Comment: @jackjay ok Thanks

Comment: @SSALPHAX now I found the problem, my problem is I can't pass the value to textview. I do it like this"Toast.makeText(activity_tv9.this,"Thanks "+val1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" to test, it works.